# Bang IE7 - What does it mean?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

That title isn't quite as crazy it seems. I promise!!

While researching for another question, I noticed the following in Stack Overflow's stylesheets:

```
...
width: auto;
...
width: 650px!ie7;
padding-bottom: 20px!ie7;
...
```

Is this an odd type of conditional styling? Is this a mistake? Assuming it isn't a mistake, does this work with all IE versions? Is there a way of specifying that a given rule should only be applied to versions of IE greater than – say – 7?

I have never encountered of this before – I've always used conditional comments for IE-specific styles (and for what it's worth, I prefer keeping all IE-specific styles completely separate).

Comment: @shadow Yep. :) Please see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclamation_mark

Comment: BTW what browser do you use? Is it IE?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I have heard of this before, but not with the exact text `!ie7`.

I found a reference here: http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csshacks3.shtml

> !ie
>
> Internet Explorer 7 fixed one of the
>   issues with the !important identifier,
>   but it still has problems when the
>   identifier has an error in it. If an
>   illegal identifier name is used in
>   place of important, Internet Explorer
>   7 and below will handle the property
>   normally instead of failing.
>   Therefore, in any style declaration
>   block, you can include properties
>   intended to only apply to Internet
>   Explorer and add an !ie identifier.
>   **Almost any word can be used in place
>   of ie.**
>
> **The !ie identifier allows the property
>   to be applied in IE 7 and below. It
>   may or may not work in future
>   versions. Warning: this uses invalid
>   CSS!**

So, `width: 650px!ie7;` will be applied in only IE 7 and below.

The actual text `ie7` is not required, but it's a sensible string to use, to remind people of the purpose behind the hack.

Comment: Good catch, never heard of this. But a dangerous and ugly hack to use, no doubt

Comment: I've never personally used this, but I'd wager that whoever wrote the Stack Overflow CSS knows what they're doing, so it must work. I usually just stick with conditional comments loading an extra stylesheet for each version of IE which must be supported, because *everyone* understands that.

Comment: Awesome find! I'll upvote this in... 48 minutes, but for now, I'll mark it as the answer. :)