# What does !ie7 do in this style?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bang IE7 - What does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987418/bang-ie7-what-does-it-mean)

I'm currently working through differences in the way IE 7 renders my web site, and I came across this style in the StackOverflow stylesheet:

```
#header {
    width:960px;
    height:120px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-bottom:15px !ie7;
}
```

Could someone explain what `!ie7` is?  I'm wondering if this is something I could make use of as well.  Apologies if this is something obvious; my knowledge of CSS is still fairly basic.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987418/bang-ie7-what-does-it-mean/4987481#4987481 Very similar, can't remember if it's identical, the extra space might be significant.

Comment: @thirtydot, thank you, I didn't think to search for "Bang IE7" :)

Comment: No problem, I don't think many people would think to :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example it means `padding-bottom:15px` will only work in `<IE7` and not any other browser. The property referenced with !IE7 means it will only work in `<IE7`. Try it out in the link i provided below and view it using different browsers. I have !IE7 on the border property. So border will only show if browser is IE7 or below.

### See working example at http://jsfiddle.net/qGv4P/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/qGv4P/1/ :) - you can use whatever text you like, see my linked answer on this question.

Comment: Yes with exception to `important`. IE7 is just a label so you know what it's for when you look at your stylesheet.

Comment: This is something new. Are there similar examples for FF, Opera, Safari, Chrome, etc?

Answer (score 0):

!-Key means important for special browser but I think ur stylesheet is missing a value because !ie7 doesn't do anything or it means the command padding-box:15px is a total waste for ie7 and such should be avoided on ie7.

Comment: Actually, it -only- processes if the browser is IE7 or lower. Read @thirtydot's comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's a logical operator of Not. E.G. not Internet Explorer 7.

I've not seen it in this format. Often, it's included in if statements in a document head to determine which .css file to use, based on the browser making the request.

My guess would be it is purposed to not use that line if the requesting browser is IE7.

Comment: CSS does not support logical operators. It's a hack that is only processed by IE7 and lower. See @thirtydot's comment on the question for a link to the explanation.