# IE8 vs IE7 html formatting

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, internet-explorer-7

I've been struggling with getting a div container element to center along with it's child content and is starting to get frustrating.  The inline styling I have for div is as follows:

```
    <body id="body1" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center">
        <div id="container" style="position: relative; width: 910px; margin: 0px auto;">
             <!---Child Content--->      
    .
    .
.
</div>
    </body>
```

When these settings are viewed in IE7, the div container is off-set to the right as the below pic shows:

[image]

In order to center it I have to add define the right property in its position style in order to push it toward the center:

```
    <body id="body1" style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center">
        <div id="container" style="position: relative; right: 425px; width: 910px; margin: 0px auto;">
<!---Child Content--->      
        .
        .
    .
        </div>
    </body>
```

This fixes the problem for IE7:

[image]

Predictably however, the formatting is off in IE8, Firefox, Chrome, etc. when applying the second styling format above:

Firefox (same behavior in Chrome and IE8)

[image]

Hope it's a simple fix, I don't understand why IE7 treats the styling differently.  Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:

@Dan Hardy, adrift - If I could accept both your answers I would, thanks guys it worked.  That is very strange behavior, I figured by now I wouldn't have to cater to specific browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put `!ie7` after the width attribute, it will be ignored by browsers other than IE 7:

`right: 425px !ie7;`

For a better explanation of this, see this SO question and the accepted answer:

[Bang IE7 - What does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987418/bang-ie7-what-does-it-mean)

I leave it to you to decide whether this is too 'hacky', but it is used in the Stack Overflow css.

Comment: I really like shorthand notation and try to use it when I can.

Answer (score 2):

This paves the way for a fix, but isn't strictly a fix:

You can add conditional browser specific statements into your HTML code:

http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Basically what you can do is add the comment's below to your page:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="conditional_ie_7_stylesheet.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Between those tags you could add the necessary styling to offset the issues on specific browsers.

As I've said, this doesn't fix your CSS problem but it provides an alternative.

Comment: Thanks for your help and resources Daniel, I'll keep this approach and link handy.

Comment: After reading more in the link adrift provided, I see that that particular approach, although it fixes the issue, is considered a non-standard hack.  I want to try to stick to standard, just a personal style, so I'll probably change to the format you provided.

Comment: I suppose the difference between my solution and the accepted solution is - if you have a large amount of styles you need to change, you could collect them all in a specific stylesheet as above. If you are only changing one or two little things then the accepted solution works just as well!

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get the html in the original question to work fine in IE7 when you remove the `position: relative` from the div.  There is also the chance that there are interactions in the content html/css that is causing the underlying issue so if this doesn't fix it could you post the content html/css that you have that demonstrates the issue in the screenshots that would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks Aliester, the code is actually for a template that will be applied across several pages, one of the requirements is to have the container div be relatively positioned.