# CSS Compatibility IE7 - IE8 problem

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, ie8-compatibility-mode, cross-browser

Problem:

Thanks for taking the time to read this. I'm having a problem which I need to solve as simple as possible. There's a website I'm re-developing, but since I updated to IE8, I've totaly forgotten about IE7, but ofcourse, there are still people using it.

I need to know what specific things I should change for this site to display the same way as it does in IE8. But I don't know where to start. Is there anyone with experience in this, who can give me a guideline? Are there scripts for doing so?

URL: http://www.testsite.c-tz.nl/

If you view this with IE8 it looks perfect.

But if you view it with IE7, things are not where they supposed to be, very ugly.

Comment: This question is way too broad.

Comment: There are no hard and fast rules. Work element by element until it looks the same. You should ideally test in all the common browsers.

Comment: you can test with your IE8, use the developer toolbar and switch it to IE7 standards

Comment: lol wtf, I get - points for asking a question?? lol.. :-/ I was just wondering what people thought of it. Christ, I even presented a link so people can watch the code!! Goddamnit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other said, your question is to broad. You'll need to break it down in smaller problems - which will possibly help you solve it yourself along the way.

One thing I did notice: IE has problems with `display: inline-block` on elements, which were orignally `block` elements. Either use `span` (only possible if it doesn't contain block elements), or use another method to places blocks side by side such as float.

BTW, you have far too many `div`s in your HTML. It's not necessary to wrap every `img`, every `ul`, etc. in it's own `div`. Usually any styles you apply to the `div` can just as well be applied you the "wrapped" element directly.

Comment: it's true IE6/7 do not support inline-block fully, but no need to change to an inline element, just add a new rule for all the elements which have inline-block and add this (at the end of the sheet after all the other rules): `.class1, .class2, .class3, li, h3 {display: inline !ie7;}` substitute those class names and elements for all the ones that are inline-block in your sheet, and put it separately don't try to add into the existing rules ;)

Comment: What is this `!ie7` declaration? Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: it's hack for feeding CSS to ie7 and below only, you could just put the `display: inline` rule in a conditional comment without the `!ie7` bit.. [More here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987418/bang-ie7-what-does-it-mean) the actual text "ie7" is not important, but serves as a reminder what (or who ;)) the rule is for

Comment: From the question you liked to: "Warning: this uses invalid CSS!" This is a good reason to avoid this. There are better (and valid) ways to apply styles to specific versions of IE.

Comment: yes I said a conditional comment would do fine, better is subjective, it's whatever your preference is really.. it's a lot harder to type a full conditonal rule in these here comments ;)) -  the point is that the `display:inline` rule will avoid unnecessarily changing the HTML

Comment: This was a very helpful post! Thnx =] I'll use the !ie7 rules and see what I can do with it! Very helpful. Still angry though at the stupid folks that gave me - points for asking a question.. Idiots, lol.

Comment: I used the !ie7 rule, very handy! Did exactly what was mentioned, made a general class for all inline-block elements: {display: inline !ie7; zoom:1 !ie7;} I also noticed that, in my case, 'display: inline-block;' adding a rule after that -> 'float:left !ie7' helped me because 'inline-block' isn't recognised, and i had TWO elements in a div nexto eachother. It becamse harder with THREE elements next to eachoter. What I did was:  change the width, one time general "width: 10em" and line after that: "width: 7em !ie7" because somehow 'em'  isn't a general term for ie7 against IE8/firefox/etc...

Answer (score 0):

This is not a cool idea... But you can try when you are sick with very old browsers like ie6 or ie5 ...

1.use javascript to detect the browser and version..

2.later use the similar way to redirect the visitor to download the IE 8..

```
<script>
 if(''+browserName+''+fullVersion+'' == "Microsoft Internet Explorer6.0" )
{

alert("You're using an Old Browser.Update the browser to view the website.(or) Try Latest Google Chrome , Firefox , Safari, Opera")
window.location = "http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=43" 
}
//document.write(''+browserName+''+fullVersion+''); 
</script>
```