# Modernizr: how do I detect CSS display:table-cell support?

Tags: html, css, modernizr

I want to use `display: table` and `display: table-cell` for my layout in browsers that support it. In IE7 I simply want to float my columns (since I assume it's not possible to get it to work in that browser), but cannot find anything about how to do it using Modernizr. Can anyone help me please?

I suppose I could use a browser conditional, but was hoping to not have to break out another CSS file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you want to do is apply a single different rule for IE7 and less, I'd be tempted not to use Modernizr for this specific job.

Simply do something like this, to avoid having to `"break out another CSS file"`:

```
#menu li {
    display: table-cell;
    *float: left;
}
```

This uses the [Star Property Hack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Star_hack) to provide a rule to only IE7 and below.

Another option is the [`!ie7` hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987418/bang-ie7-what-does-it-mean/4987481#4987481), which is for some odd reason my highest voted answer.

Comment: If OP cares about validity, use `* + html #menu li { float: left; }` instead. (Sure we don't need `* html` at this point... right?)

Comment: Haha :) Good point about the validity, and thanks for providing the workaround. And yes, let's forget about IE6.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I like having valid code when I can, so I think I'll use the "*+HTML" hack.

Answer (score 2):

... And if you want to use Modernizr, you could use this snippet:

```
(function() {
    var displayTests = ["table", "table-caption", "table-cell",
    "table-column", "table-column-group", "table-footer-group",
    "table-header-group", "table-row", "table-row-group"];

    var rules = document.createElement("div").style;

    for (var c=0; c<displayTests.length; c++) {
            var testValue = displayTests[c];
            Modernizr.addTest("display" + testValue, function() {
                    try {
                            rules.display = testValue;
                            return rules.display == testValue;
                    } catch (e) {
                            return false;
                    }
            })
    }
}());
```

Source [[Link]](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/185)

Answer (score 0):

IE 8 does not tell the truth when the created element is a 'tfoot', and the display value is 'table-header-group'.  The following snippet will not fail, even though IE 8 ignores the CSS setting and continues to display 'tfoot' below 'tbody'.

```
try {
    var x = document.createElement('tfoot').style;
    x.display = 'table-header-group';
    console.log('Both IE 8 and Chrome end up here.');
} catch (e) {
    console.log('Except IE 8 should have ended up here, since it does not move the tfoot element.');
}
```

It might be 'correct', in the sense that 'tfoot' has already set display to 'table-footer-group'; but it's 'wrong' in the sense that it (a) doesn't allow the user to override, and (b) doesn't tell the user that it isn't going to work.  I haven't tested other browsers.