# Use Modernizr to make IE display table-cells

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, modernizr

I have used some jQuery to make IE `display:table-cell;`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($.browser.msie)
  {
    $(".tablecell").wrap("<td />");
    $(".tablerow").wrap("<tr />");
    $(".table").wrapInner("<table />");
  }
});
```

Now as `.browser` became obsolete and is not supported anymore after jQuery 1.9, I downloaded **modernizr** and included it in my projet...  How should I use it now (the famous and not very clear *feature detection*) instead of my js code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modernizr: how do I detect CSS display:table-cell support?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783760/modernizr-how-do-i-detect-css-displaytable-cell-support)

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn: my problem is not specific to IE7, but in general to IE...

Comment: @Serge The non-accepted answer over there is the sanctioned way to do it I think (https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/185)

Comment: There is a relevant answer in that thread

Comment: what answer "a rule to only IE7 and below" or the "!ie7 hack"?

Answer (score 0):

Tried to use this one (a not very elegant solution without modernizr):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/msie|trident/i)) {
        $(".tablecell").wrap("<td />");
        $(".tablerow").wrap("<tr />");
        $(".table").wrapInner("<table />");
    }
});
```

it detects the browser but unfortunately the rendering result is still not OK...  (not like in Chrome, by eg)...