# !important or !notimportant in IE6 and 7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

A friend of mine is stating that it doesn't matter what word you use after the `!` key in Cascading Style Sheets, it will still gain that extra weight, as long it is Internet Explorer 6 or 7.

This means that I could write `!notimportant` and it will still be considered as important. My question for this thread is: **is this true?**

I can't try for myself since I do not have any Windows machine (not at work or home). Would be interesting to know though.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you didn't try yourself before posting this question?

Comment: @Bondye: Did you read the question? The OP already explains why.

Comment: Because I don't have access to any internet explorer. If you read the thread you will notice.

Comment: Yes I did, He can't try but he just don't know how to try

Comment: Just a side note, it's logical, because !!important = important (double negation). It's not logical that !important = important (void negation?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is correct. IE6/IE7 incorrectly treats `!` followed by any identifiers and whitespace as an `!important` token instead of completely ignoring the declaration. Some references:

- http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csshacks3.shtml
- [Bang IE7 - What does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987418/bang-ie7-what-does-it-mean) (with an example of `!ie7` on this very site as well as a link to the above reference)

The spec states that `!` can only be followed by case-insensitive `important` with optional whitespace and comments separating them for it to be recognized as an important declaration. You can see this in the [grammar](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner):

```
"!"({w}|{comment})*{I}{M}{P}{O}{R}{T}{A}{N}{T}  {return IMPORTANT_SYM;}
```

So while these are valid important declarations:

```css
background: transparent !important;
background: transparent !IMPORTANT;
background: transparent !ImPoRtAnT;
background: transparent ! important;
background: transparent !   important;
background: transparent !   /**/important;
background: transparent ! /**/ /**/ important;
background: transparent !/**/important;
```

These are invalid and should be ignored (don't even try to apply the background):

```css
background: transparent !notimportant;
background: transparent !NOTIMPORTANT;
background: transparent !NoTiMpOrTaNt;
background: transparent ! notimportant;
background: transparent !   notimportant;
background: transparent !ie7;
background: transparent !abc;
background: transparent !_;
```

But IE6/7 will treat them *all* like valid `!important` statements and apply the background. IE8 and later will correctly ignore them, although this may or may not be reproducible in those versions in Compatibility View.

Note that while the [Jigsaw W3C CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator) reports `!/**/important` as invalid (`!` immediately followed by a comment instead of whitespace), that is a bug with the validator parser. It's definitely valid according to the grammar.

Comment: @Damien Overeem: To be fair, this was IE at least six years ago. It's gotten quite better recently, although some things understandably never change.

Comment: They do try.. but damn it took a long time before they got their heads out of their arses and started to comply with standards that most others were allready using... Example: lets build microsoft silverlight, about 2 years before everyone ditches flash for html5 ;)